# Access property from outside a method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to find the users current city.

```
@interface WeatherViewController ()
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *test;
@end

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    for (CLPlacemark * placemark in placemarks) {
        _test = [placemark locality];
        NSLog(@"%@", _test);
    }
}];
}
```

Running the app logs the current city based on the location.

If I try and run `NSLog(@"%@", _test);` outside the method locationManager the data retruned is null. Can someone explain why `_test` is only returning a value inside the for loop?

Comment: Because test is released after the block finishes.

Answer (score -2):

You should use the dotSyntax, self.test = [placeMark locality]
Chances are that this is a memory management issue!

Comment: This is an *asynchronous method* issue, and not a memory management issue.

Comment: Silly me, this is totally right! _test is not set UNTIL the location has been found :- )